# Angular 6 unit testing static mock response

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am testing an Angular component which calls a service method. Within the component, I modify some fields of the response before proceeding, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.myMethod(requestData).subscribe(response => {
      response.list.forEach(item => {
        item.someField = someValue;
      })
    });
    ...
}
```

For testing, I created a mock response like this:

```
const mockServiceResponse = {
    list: [],
    ...
}

const myServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService',['myMethod']);
myServiceSpy .myMethod.and.returnValue( of(mockServiceResponse ) );
```

The problem is; I have several test cases, and ngOnInit is called for each test case. As I modify the service response fields, at each run **mockServiceResponse** object is modified, and second test case gets the modified version of the response. This is not a problem for the componenet because I actually get a new response each time I call the method, but for testing it causes my test cases to fail. Any ideas on how can I get a fresh version of **mockServiceResponse** for each test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useThisValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mockValue))` to copy the complete object from the mock value and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `beforeEach` to set up the test conditions for each test. You can nest `describe` and add more `beforeEach` calls to control how often things are executed.

This example will set up your testing module once. It will create a "mockServiceResponse" and mock `myMethod` once per test in the spec.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    const myServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService',['myMethod'])    

    beforeEach(() => {
        /* 
         * Set up angular testing module
         * Declare your component(s)
         * Provide your spy as the implementation for the service you want to mock
         * This will run once for the entire spec
         */ 
    });

    describe('some more specific description', () => {
       //This will run before each test
       beforeEach(() => {
            let mockServiceResponse = {
                list: [],
                ...
            };
            myServiceSpy .myMethod.and.returnValue( of(mockServiceResponse ) );
        });

        it('does something', () => {
            //run your test
        });

        it('does another thing', () => {
            //run your test
        });
    });
});
```